# Does passing a large object into a function affect speed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, object

Passing large json-object `message`:

```
def foobar(message):
    ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_handler(message):
    foobar(message)
```

Passing only two strings:

```
def foobar(chat_id, text):
    ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_handler(message):
    foobar(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Comment: You can always test this yourself using the [timeit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: In both cases you are only passing references. The size of the referenced object is not relevant *at this point*. So in theory using two arguments should be slower.

Comment: If you issue is about speed, and see that the time of the processing is longer, try using numpy. Many functions of python you can be used  at Numpy and is faster, check it and will see

https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference

Comment: It is possible that `@bot.message_handler` processes the large message object under the hood, which could be the bottleneck if `foobar` is fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python always uses a "pass-by-reference" model. So by definition, it shouldn't affect your code performance directly. However, dealing with larger object can.